# iOS, Objective-C, iPhone , iPad, version issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

How can we know an app will work in all version. For example I am working a project in which this code works fine in version 7, But does not work in version 8 :

```
_selectorType = ImageTypeChooseImage;
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [_viewController  presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];    but in latest version above code does not run, for latest version I this code runs fine:
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------     Works fine in version 8 :

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self openPhotoPicker:sourceType];
}];
```

In short, How do we know, if an app runs fine in a particular version, So, it will also run in all version. (Obviously, we do not have device with all version, so that we can run and ensure)

Comment: Test as much as you can, use the simulators, beta test, read the docs for iOS updates

Comment: Thank @ Jammycoder, But is there no any other easy way, by which we can ensure an app will run fine in all version, I  think Apple can not lose this point. (They provided us something, but we don't have idea).

Comment: Please, Reply if anyone has easy solution/idea, I will thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - test your app in All relevant simulators: different devices and different SDKs.

Secondly - there isn't any alternative for real devices. after you test it with simulator - the QA should check it with a real device.

Comment: You welcome ! if it's the right answer - i would appreciate if you'll tag it as the right one.

Comment: Please help me , Anyone please unblock me ,when I click ask question I get this message :

You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.